# Solving a "tree-equation"?

Tags: graph-algorithms, term-rewriting-systems

Given two trees A and B, each of their nodes except some leaves have a "type" (which also determines the number of children, the node has, having that type). The leaves which don't have a type are identified by letters (variables) (a,b,c,...). Each letter may occur multiple times in a tree.

The task is to devise an algorithm to 'solve' the 'equation' A=B, i.e. assign trees to the variables (possibly containing other variables). One tree (x) equals to an other (y) iff x and y are the same variables or the root of both have the same type and their respective children are equal.

In the following the "types" are numbers.

**Example 1:**

**A** tree is

```
1
|-2
|-a
```

**B** tree is

```
1
|-2
|-3
```

The solution is `a->3`

**Example 2:**

**A** tree is

```
1
|-2
|-a
```

**B** tree is

```
1
|-3
|-3
```

This does not have a solution.

**Example 3:**

**A** tree is

```
1
|-2
|-a
```

**B** tree is

```
1
|-2
|-b
```

The solution is `a=b` (the equation is underdetermined so to say)

Comment: From your post it seems that the trees are *rooted* {i.e root 1 with child 2 and root 2 with child 1 are considered different trees} and that children are *ordered* {i.e that root 1 with children 2 and 3 and root 1 with children 3 and 2 are considered different}, please confirm.

Comment: @daniello indeed that is true.

Comment: In that case just doing a DFS in both trees simultaneously should do the trick, no?

Comment: Isn't this just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science) ?

Comment: @DavidEppstein looks like exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Ok, I'll upgrade this from a comment to an answer.

Comment: It should be possible to sole in linear time however article on Wikipedia does not explain it to deeply

Comment: The following is the basic description of unification.  You have a tree A and a tree B.  Both A and B contain variables which may represent numbers or entire subtrees.  You want to find a substitution for the variables of A and a substitution for the variables of B so that the two resulting trees are equivalent.  Now, maybe you don't just want any substitutions, but you want the "most general" substitutions that make the resulting trees equivalent.  I would be more than happy to talk further about this concept with you and provide more detail if it's something that you're interested in.

Comment: I've implemented a few unification algorithms. I wrote one in JavaScript a while back.  Feel free to let me know if you're looking to implement something using unification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The process you seem to be looking for (merging two descriptions of labeled trees) is called [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)). According to the linked Wikipedia article it can be solved in linear time.

Comment: For an extensive and understandable presentation of unification and its related algorithms, I would recommend the famous "All that" book : Franz Baader and Tobias Nipkow (1998). Term Rewriting and All That. Cambridge University Press.